# Persistently setting display-line-numbers to relative in emacs init file

Tags: init-file

I am attempting to set up the new emacs 26.1 `display-line-numbers-mode` as described in this comment: [hybrid line number mode in emacs?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/19532/hybrid-line-number-mode-in-emacs#comment56950_19532)

I have added this to my .emacs file:

```
(setq display-line-numbers 'relative
      display-line-numbers-current-absolute t)
```

When I evaluate the above expression the desired behavior is produced, but it is not persistent. For example, it is not automatically evaluated on restarting emacs, and when I try to use my keybinding toggle:

```
(global-set-key (kbd "C-c l") 'display-line-numbers-mode)
```

The line numbers that are toggled are not relative.

What is the appropriate way to set `display-line-numbers` to `relative` in my configuration file so that using the keybinding results in relative line numbers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `setq-default` to set buffer-local default values.  Or, make sure you are in the desired buffer if you wish to use `setq`.

`C-h v` [aka `M-x describe-variable`] for `display-line-numbers`:  "*. . . Automatically becomes buffer-local when set.*"

`display-line-numbers-current-absolute` is a global variable.  [How do we know?  Because the `*Help*` buffer for describing that variable does not mention anything about it being buffer-local.]

The variable `display-line-numbers-type` is a global variable with a doc-string that states:  "*The default type of line numbers to use in ‘display-line-numbers-mode’.  See ‘display-line-numbers’ for value options.*"  Therefore, the O.P. could use `(setq display-line-numbers-type 'relative)` in the `.emacs` or `init.el` file to achieve the desired result.

Comment: Apologies - I'm new to emacs so I'm still not sure how to proceed. I've tried `setq-default` with `display-line-numbers 'relative` in my .emacs file but it does not seem to work.

Comment: If I evaluate `(setq-default display-line-numbers 'realtive)` and then type `M-x describe-variable RET display-line-numbers RET`, the `*Help*` buffer says:  "... *Its value is ‘realtive’.  Original value was nil*."  If you place that same code in your `.emacs` or `init.el` file, it should show the same thing if you restart Emacs and type `M-x describe-variable ...`  Is that what it says?

Comment: Yes, that is true, and it is enabled in all new buffers. However, using `C-c l` as set above reverts it to absolute line numbering.

Comment: `C-c l` is *undefined* in a new installation of Emacs 26.1 (with no user-configuration) in `fundamental-mode`.  What function is your `C-c l` bound to?  Type:  `C-h k` or `M-x describe-key`.

Comment: I'm trying to enable toggling of line number mode as well. I'm using: `(global-set-key (kbd "C-c l") 'display-line-numbers-mode)`

Comment: If we type `M-x find-function RET display-line-numbers-mode RET`, we see that the variable `display-line-numbers` is set to the value of `display-line-numbers-type`.  And, we already know now that `display-line-numbers` is a buffer-local variable and `setq` sets that variable locally in the buffer that has been selected.   If we type `M-x describe-variable RET display-line-numbers-type RET`, we see that it is a global variable whose value is `t`.  FYI:  I had to evaluate `(require 'display-line-numbers)` to load the entire library to look-up the aforementioned variable.  Set it to `'relative`.

Comment: Perfect. (Thanks for the lesson also.)

Answer (score 1):

So I am an emacs novice myself, but the way I understood it (and have it in my init.el file):

```
;; set type of line numbering (global variable)
(setq display-line-numbers-type 'relative) 

;; activate line numbering in all buffers/modes
(global-display-line-numbers-mode)
```

You could also be more specific and only have line numbering in a subset of major modes by using hooks. For instance:

```
;; Activate line numbering in programming modes
(add-hook 'prog-mode-hook 'display-line-numbers-mode)
```

[Source](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/278/how-do-i-display-line-numbers-in-emacs-not-in-the-mode-line) for the last snippet.